# Advanced AMPscript - "Weighted" content on a 1:1 basis?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm considering how Marketing Cloud can compete versus some of the competing offerings - and one particular use case I've seen is the whole concept of Dynamic Preferences. Imagine the following setup:

I'm a subscriber with a preference for category **A of 1.0**, category **B of 0.7** and category **C of 0.5**

The content we are using - we're pulling in via AMPscript - and the way we do it is via a mapping table, essentially - a column with a content id, one with category and one with a "weight" column which signals importance for us as a company.

For simplicity, I'm illustrating with 1 content per category (in reality there may be 1 to 30 content pieces).

- Cat A Main with weight of 0.30
- Cat B Main with weight of 0.70
- Cat C Main with weight of 0.95

This yields the following scores:

- Cat A Main = 0.300 (1.00 * 0.30)
- Cat B Main = 0.490 (0.70 * 0.70)
- Cat C Main = 0.475 (0.50 * 0.95)

Thus, the result for me as a subscriber would be that i should see Cat B Main.

When thinking of this design, I've gotten to the point where i can envision the creation of content, the mapping tables, sticking the logic in a *for loop*, however, I am coming up short on how to return the "Max" value for my scoring variable which i create at send time (in ampscript).

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, does this absolutely have to run at send time - or could this logic be built into a DataExtension/Query activity and put into an Automation? Will the dynamic content only be a small part of the email, or will the result of Cat A/B/C determine the whole email?

Comment: Hi Cameron - it has to be at send time I'm afraid. Building a DE that stores the content ID for each block used in an email could make sense for some use cases - so nice suggestion - however, the email can also be triggered - e.g. an abandoned basket type of thing, therefore send time solutions is what I'm after :) The email is comprised of say 10 blocks, where each block could be subject to be generated as a dynamic block as indicated here.

Comment: What's the expected volume of subscribers per send for this email?

Comment: In most scenarios it would be no more than 25.000/hour, but, ideally it would support a full blast, newsletter style, to around 1-3 million subscribers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a fascinating scenario!

I'm aware of two ways to sort with email scripting -- [**LookupOrderedRows()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuporderedrows/) and with a comparator in [**Server-Side JavaScript (SSJS)**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/server_side_javascript/)

The **LookupOrderedRows()** function will require you to do as [**@CameronRobert**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/40604/cameron-robert) suggested -- calculate the weights outside of the email with a Query Activity.  This would also be my recommendation if it fits.

Here's a quick-and-dirty SSJS sort example, which may be enough to get you started:

```
<script language="JavaScript" runat="server">

  Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

  var de = DataExtension.Init("AMPScriptTest3");
  var rows = de.Rows.Lookup(["LookupKey"], [1]);

  for(var i=0; rows.length>i; i++) {
    Write("<br>rows["+i+"]['Number1']: " + rows[i]['Number1']);
  }

  rows = rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(b.Number1) - parseFloat(a.Number1);
  });

  Write("<br>");

  for(var i=0; rows.length>i; i++) {
    Write("<br>rows["+i+"]['Number1']: " + rows[i]['Number1']);
  }

</script>
```

**Output**

```
rows[0]['Number1']: 10
rows[1]['Number1']: 11
rows[2]['Number1']: 12
rows[3]['Number1']: 15

rows[0]['Number1']: 15
rows[1]['Number1']: 12
rows[2]['Number1']: 11
rows[3]['Number1']: 10
```

The problem with SSJS -- which is why I asked about send volume -- is that it's *super* slow.  SFMC folks do not recommend using SSJS in emails.  It's good on occasion, because it adds the possibility of arrays and sorting, two things that AMPScript is lacking.

EDIT: Also you can sort in an XSLT (using XPath 1.0 methods) in SFMC if your data is in XML format.

Comment: Hi adam ! Thanks for this! :-)

Essentially, it means that for high volume sends, unless we get an XML type data feed, it really isn't possible at present, due to the lack of arrays and sorting capabilities of ampscript right? 

For lower volumes, we could leverage SSJS, right? :)

Comment: Your scenario sounds possible (and fun to build) with SSJS.  I'd just expect the sends to take longer.

Comment: Would you have any indication of the volumes it could process? for instance 2 million emails per hour? or? :)